# Oracle DBMS_SESSION SET_CONTEXT does not store a value

Tags: oracle, session, global-variables

I am trying to produced a system in Oracle where a context stores a value; if a table is updated (update/insert/delete) in any session, the value should be increased. The problem I am having is that even though I'm certain I've set it up correctly, it doesn't seem to work - the context does not seem to actually store the value. I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.1.0.

For the minimum possible example:

I have a context (the ACCESSED GLOBALLY clause should make it so the values are accessible across all Oracle sessions, which is what I want):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT MM_CONTEXT USING PCKG_TESTGLOBALS ACCESSED GLOBALLY;
```

I have a debugging table:

```
CREATE TABLE DATALOG (
  DATALOG_SEQ NUMBER,
  AT_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000)
);
```

I have a sequence to support the `DATALOG` table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_DATALOG;
```

Now the PCKG_TESTGLOBALS package is required which has access to the `MM_CONTEXT` context and can update elements of it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PCKG_TESTGLOBALS IS

  PROCEDURE Log(FunctionName IN VARCHAR2, Msg IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE SetParameter(p_name IN VARCHAR2, p_value IN VARCHAR2);

  FUNCTION GetTABLEID RETURN NUMBER;

END PCKG_TESTGLOBALS;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PCKG_TESTGLOBALS IS

  CONTEXT_NAME CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'MM_CONTEXT';

  PROCEDURE Log(FunctionName IN VARCHAR2, Msg IN VARCHAR2) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO DATALOG(DATALOG_SEQ, MESSAGE) VALUES (SQ_DATALOG.NEXTVAL, FunctionName || ':' || Msg);
    COMMIT;
  END;

  PROCEDURE SetParameter(p_name IN VARCHAR2, p_value IN VARCHAR2) IS
    ActualValue VARCHAR2(10000);
  BEGIN
    Log('SetParameter', 'ENTERED');
    Log('SetParameter', 'SETTING "' || p_name || '" TO "' || p_value || '"');
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT(CONTEXT_NAME, p_name, p_value);
    ActualValue := SYS_CONTEXT(CONTEXT_NAME, p_name);
    Log('SetParameter', 'READ "' || p_name || '" AS "' || ActualValue || '"');
    Log('SetParameter', 'EXITED');
  END;

  PROCEDURE Initialise IS
    iTmp NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    Log('Initialise', 'ENTERED');
    IF SYS_CONTEXT(CONTEXT_NAME, 'LOWNID') IS NULL THEN
      iTmp := DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM;
      Log('Initialise', '"LOWNID" has no value, writing "' || iTmp || '"');
      PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.SetParameter('LOWNID', iTmp);
    END IF;
    Log('Initialise', 'EXITED');
  END;

  FUNCTION GetTABLEID RETURN NUMBER IS
    ReadValue VARCHAR2(32767);
  BEGIN
    Log('GetTABLEID', 'ENTERED');
    ReadValue := SYS_CONTEXT(CONTEXT_NAME, 'LOWNID');
    Log('GetTABLEID', 'READ VALUE OF "LOWNID" AS "' || ReadValue || '"');
    Log('GetTABLEID', 'EXITED');
    RETURN TO_NUMBER(ReadValue);
  END;

BEGIN

  Initialise;

END PCKG_TESTGLOBALS;
/
```

So to explain the functions in `PCKG_TESTGLOBALS`:

`Log` - Logs a message for debugging reasons.

`SetParameter` - Takes a name/value pair and stores this using `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT` in the `MM_CONTEXT`

`Initialise` - For a session variable `LOWNID` it checks if the variable is null, and if it is, sets it to a random value, using `SetParameter`. `Initialise` is called when the package is first used in a session.

`GetTABLEID` - this returns the value stored in the session variable `LOWNID`.

Finally there is a trigger called `TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN` which is on the table `LOWN` - the structure of which doesn't matter here, any table would do - and fires after any DML, INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON LOWN
DECLARE
  iTmp NUMBER;
BEGIN
  PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.Log('TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN', 'ENTERED');
  iTmp := PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.GetTABLEID;
  PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.Log('TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN', 'Read Value "' || iTmp || '"');
  iTmp := NVL(iTmp, 1) + 1;
  PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.Log('TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN', 'Updated Value "' || iTmp || '"');
  PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.SetParameter('LOWNID', iTmp);
  PCKG_TESTGLOBALS.Log('TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN', 'EXITED');
END TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN;
/
```

The purpose of this trigger is thus: Whenever the table `LOWN` is updated, the value of the session variable `LOWNID` is read back, and has 1 added to it, and is written back in.

If in a new session I do a few consecutive UPDATEs on the `LOWN` table, I get these results in my debugging table (`SELECT MESSAGE FROM DATALOG ORDER BY DATALOG_SEQ`)

```
Initialise:ENTERED
Initialise:"LOWNID" has no value, writing "805223597"
SetParameter:ENTERED
SetParameter:SETTING "LOWNID" TO "805223597"
SetParameter:READ "LOWNID" AS ""
SetParameter:EXITED
Initialise:EXITED
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:ENTERED
GetTABLEID:ENTERED
GetTABLEID:READ VALUE OF "LOWNID" AS ""
GetTABLEID:EXITED
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:Read Value ""
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:Updated Value "2"
SetParameter:ENTERED
SetParameter:SETTING "LOWNID" TO "2"
SetParameter:READ "LOWNID" AS ""
SetParameter:EXITED
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:EXITED
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:ENTERED
GetTABLEID:ENTERED
GetTABLEID:READ VALUE OF "LOWNID" AS ""
GetTABLEID:EXITED
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:Read Value ""
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:Updated Value "2"
SetParameter:ENTERED
SetParameter:SETTING "LOWNID" TO "2"
SetParameter:READ "LOWNID" AS ""
SetParameter:EXITED
TR_ONDML_TL_LOWN:EXITED
```

You can see from the example that it passes in the value correctly to `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT`, but it doesn't seem to store the value at all. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Strange, I tried this but called the trigger code just in a pl/sql block, and it worked for me.  Look correct.

Comment: @OldProgrammer it looks correct to me too! Very frustrating!

Comment: This is a globally accessible context, so you need to set `client_id` to match the client_identifier for the session. If they don't match, the context will not retrieve the values you stored. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG77432

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I've tested it with `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT(CONTEXT_NAME, p_name, p_value, USER, NULL);` and this works great; if you supply it as an answer I'll mark it closed

Comment: @JeffreyKemp P.S. Thanks, this was killing me xD

Comment: @JeffreyKemp ah, scratch that, I just tested it again and it doesn't give me the results I expect :|

Comment: @JeffreyKemp from the doc you linked to "This combination enables an application context to be accessed by multiple sessions, as long as the username setting is the same throughout. " - that's what I want, but I still get the same results

Comment: Check the client_identifier in your session. Firstly, I believe I was incorrect to say that you must set client_id or user, this only applies if you want to make the context keep separate values for individual client sessions. I think you should leave the username unset, but note that if the client_identifier (`SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','client_identifier')`) changes, the session will not see the values.

Comment: In other words, if session 1 happens to have client_identifier = 123 and sets the context with no client_id, it will not see the context value.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I came to this conclusion myself yesterday when doing more investigation; you're absolutely right. Some third-party triggers in our database are messing with the CLIENT_IDENTIFIER so we no longer have access to the context variables. If you stick that in as an answer I'll gladly accept! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a session to see a value of a Globally Accessible context, its `client_identifier` (as per `SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','client_identifier')`) must match the `client_id` parameter that was used in the call to `DBMS_SESSION.set_context`.

If your `set_context` call doesn't set `client_id` it defaults to NULL; in this case, the session will only see the new value if its `client_identifier` is also NULL.

If the session takes any particular value for `client_identifier`, you must use this same value in the call to `set_context`.

In your case, you want a global variable that is accessible by all sessions; if your sessions are getting random values for `client_identifier`, you may need to set it to NULL before running your code, then (perhaps) restore its value before returning control to the caller.